# need to change htaccess rewrite code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have just had a problem with a Codeigniter site where, after the hosting company had migrated files to a new server, I could no longer navigate away from the home page. I Googled a forum with a similar issue  and the answer was my htacess file. It was previously like this:

```
 Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the given solution was to add a '?' character after 'index.php'. I did that and everything then worked OK.

I have tried hard to understand htaccess code and syntax and read many documents but they might as well be written in Chinese for all the sense I can get out of them. So can anyone explain why that additional '?' was needed and what it did? And if you can explain the rest of the code too I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Do you realize what `index.php/foo` and `index.php?foo` url mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new host's php handler or webserver isn't setup to handle **PATH INFO**, or the stuff after the script (index.php) that's part of the actual path, e.g.

```
/index.php/this/is/part/of/the/path_info
```

The `index.php` script is executed, and everything after can be fetched via "PATH_INFO". If the server doesn't handle this, code igniter can optionally handle the path passed in as the **QUERY STRING**. Which are parameters that follow a `?`.

None of this has anything to do with htaccess or mod_rewrite. It's just the way URLs and handlers work.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. I jumped to all the wrong conclusions about Apache weirdness. That's now clear. Still don't understand the rest of the code though!